# What strategies can I adopt for proving monotonicity of a sequence. (Do not have a problem in mind but I am open to discussions)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, soft-question

So I have been thinking about different ways/strategies of proving monotonicity of sequences, as I said in the title, I do not have a problem in mind but I want to hear different ways I may use during an exam. I will start off by listing a few:

$1)$ finding the consecutive differences between two terms and prove that it's always negative/positive.

$2)$ If a sequence is strictly positive/negative we can deduce the monotonicity by calculating the ratios between two consecutive terms and see if the ratio is less than or greater than $1$.

```
The followings are from the comments
```

$3)$Apply derivative test if the function is differentiable.

Comment: Seems good to me

Comment: If a sequence changes sign more than once, it cannot be monotonic. So the ratio approach still works, just take extra care at the sign switch.

Comment: If $a_n = f(n)$ for some differentiable function $f$, you can try testing the sign of $f'$.

Comment: @TheoBendit That's not enough by itself to conclude non-monotonicity, without more in-depth analysis of the derivative, but you can prove that a sequence is monotonic that way.

Comment: Find a function $f$ so that $f(n)=a_n$. If $f$ is also a continuous injection then $f$ is monotonic so $a_n$ is monotonic.

Answer (score 0):

Given a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ we can examine the associated function $a(x)$, take the derivative, and use the sign to determine if it's an increasing or decreasing function. This will of course imply the sequence itself is increasing or decreasing.

Simple example: $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, associated function is $a(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Taking the derivative on $]0,\infty[$ gives $a'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} < 0$ so $a_n$ is decreasing monotonically.